# Miliseconds to minute& seconds in kotlin gives wrong output

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a following value in milliseconds : 742029

Now when I try to convert it into minutes & hours then it gives me `12:22` but when you actually convert it then the actual output should be **12:36715**  You can verify on google converter. You can also verify on https://www.checkyourmath.com/convert/time/milliseconds_minutes.php

I have used following code :

```
   val minutes: Long = milliseconds / 1000 / 60
   val seconds: Long = milliseconds / 1000 % 60
```

So why it gives different output ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would anything mod 60 be a number higher than 60? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: `convert [milliseconds] into minutes & hours` vs. `…convert/time/milliseconds_minutes…` - what's it going to be? Where does the `:` (`it gives me`) come from?

Comment: : is just an explanation to differentiate between minutes & seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The online converter is telling you 12.36715 minutes, a decimal value, not 12:36

In fact, if you were to compute 0.36715 * 60 you would get something around 22 (22.029 to be precise).

So your code is correct as 742029 milliseconds equal to 12.36715 minutes that equal to 12 minutes and 22.029 seconds, i.e `0h:12m:22s`

Comment: Why would it be correct/useful to interpret/present fractional seconds base 60?

Comment: Yes correct. I want minutes & seconds only.

Comment: @greybeard I don't quite get your comment..? We use minutes and seconds mod 60 on a daily basis? What are you trying to say? Maybe the OP is trying to display the time? Do you perhaps think that something like 1.75 minutes is more readable than 01m 45s ?

Comment: @deepak if you believe my answer is correct consider accepting it, if I perhaps misunderstood your question or you still have doubts feel free to let me know

Comment: I missed that somehow, and unrelated to the code (and `12:36715`) presented in the question, (.36715) fractional *minutes* entered the picture and were (to be) re-converted to seconds - not the way to go.